# GLSL - ripling effect, bad performance on android

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl

I needed to create some ripling effect for one sprite in my game, here's the vertexShader:

```
attribute vec4 a_position; // just taking in necessary attributes
attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;

uniform mat4 u_projTrans; // Combination of view and projection matrix

varying vec2 v_texCoords;

void main() {
    v_texCoords = a_texCoord0;
    gl_Position = u_projTrans * a_position; //as I said, it is sprite so no need for modelMatrix
}
```

and here's the fragment:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
    precision mediump float;
#endif

varying vec2 v_texCoords;

uniform sampler2D u_texture; //texture of sprite
uniform float time;

void main()
{
vec2 uv;
if (time > 0.0) { // time is > 0.0 when I want the ripling effect to be applied,
vec2 cPos = -1.0 + 2.0 * v_texCoords.xy; // converting tex.Coords to -1 - 1
 float cLength = length(cPos); //taking length of it
  uv = v_texCoords.xy +( (cPos/cLength)*cos(cLength*12.0-time*4.0)*0.03 ) // just some calculations for the ripling effect
  }
 else
   uv = v_texCoords.xy; // if I don't want to use the ripling effect, I use normal texCoords

    vec4 tex = texture2D(u_texture, uv); //sampling texture 

   gl_FragColor = tex;
}
```

It all works fine, the performance's fine on PC, but when running it on android, the performance is a lot worse... As you can see, shader's are trivial but they somehow are expensive.. Anyways, sprite I draw has width about 2000 - 4000 px and height 720. Also, when I replace v_texCoords with different vector(for example vec2(1, 1)) in cPos calc: `vec2 cPos = -1.0 + 2.0 * v_texCoords.xy;` the performance improves heavily..

I don't really know what's so expensive there. If anyone had some advices, I'd be happy. Thanks in advance

Comment: For example vec2(1, 1) most likely uses some optimization on length as it is a square root of exactly 2. Can you try some other random value for that one. Maybe the shader is simply to heavy for some devices. Both cos and length operations can be very time consuming. Just a thought: Maybe you could gain significant performance by adding another texture which would describe the distance from the center on 2 components and even use another component to get the cos of a value. This will increase the texture access count but totally lose those computation calls.

Comment: I tried putting there vec2(0.36, 0.87) and the performance is still good, weird... Anyway, thanks for advice! I tried to use DuDvMap, I can see a performance gain!